# How to deal with case statements using where clause?

Tags: sql

below is my where clause it gives me syntax error near ">" sign

```
(( case when  datediff(day,a.durationfrom,a.durationto) <=30 then DATEDIFF(day, a.CompletionDate, GETDATE()) >= 40)
else DATEDIFF(day, a.CompletionDate, GETDATE()) >= 42 end as '0')
```

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: after 'then' or 'else' you are supposed to put a value, not a condition The case when statement will evaluate each "when" conditions and if none are met, it will take the "else" value.. 
Example : (( case when  datediff(day,a.durationfrom,a.durationto) <=30 then 'thisValue'
else 'thisOtherValue end as 'nameOfTheColumn')

Comment: you can not add condition in 'then' and 'else', it should be return result. Syntax:CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END;

Comment: @SujataMirge Why not? I tried with a simplified example and it works

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the logic you want to implement.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues with the syntax, firstly the extra parentheses around CASE THEN and also a use of an alias in a WHERE clause. I would try to change it to

```
case when datediff(day,a.durationfrom,a.durationto) <=30 then DATEDIFF(day, a.CompletionDate, GETDATE()) >= 40
else DATEDIFF(day, a.CompletionDate, GETDATE()) >= 42 end
```

I did also drop the outer parentheses since I don't see the need for them but they are not incorrect

Answer (score 0):

This looks like SQL Server code and SQL Server does not support a boolean type.  So, this makes no sense:

```
(case when datediff(day, a.durationfrom, a.durationto) <= 30
      then DATEDIFF(day, a.CompletionDate, GETDATE()) >= 40)
       else DATEDIFF(day, a.CompletionDate, GETDATE()) >= 42
 end) as col_0
```

Presumably, your intention is something like this:

```
(case when datediff(day, a.durationfrom, a.durationto) <= 30 and
          DATEDIFF(day, a.CompletionDate, GETDATE()) >= 40)
      then 1
      when datediff(day, a.durationfrom, a.durationto) <= 30
      then 0
      when DATEDIFF(day, a.CompletionDate, GETDATE()) >= 42
      then 1
      else 0
 end) as col_0
```